# How to dynamically get data in dropdownlist in django?

Tags: python, ajax, django

I have two dropdownlist *City Dropdownlist* and *Area Dropdownlist*

This project is working on python + Django frameowrk

when use below concept in django it's not working and give error in alert window.

So my queston is that when I choose any city from first dropdownlist then second dropdownlist data will be update from database using ajax. Maybe here Ajax is  not working. I'm not perfect in ajax so please read below code and solve my problem.

Thank you.

In index.html

```
<div class="input-field col l2 s12 m12">
    <select id="ddlcity" name="ddlcity">
        <option value="None" selected disabled>Choose City</option>
        {% for i in allcities %}
        <option value="{{ i.id }}">{{ i.city_name }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <label>Select City</label>
</div>
<div class="input-field col l3 s12 m6">
    <select id="ddlarea" name="ddlarea">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your area</option>
    </select>
    <label>Your Selected Area</label>
</div>
```

Ajax code using in index.html

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#ddlcity').change(function () {
        var data_ = $('#ddlcity').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "get",
            url: '/get/areadata/' + data_ + '/',
            data: data_,
            success: function (data) {
                $('#ddlarea').empty();

                $.each(data.d, function (key, value) {
                    $('#ddlarea').append($("<option></option>").val(value.AreaID).html(value.AreaName));
                });
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus, errorThrown);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

In urls.py

```
url(r'^/get/areadata/(\d+)/$', 'main.views.getarea', name='getareadata'),
```

In views.py

```
def getarea(request, cityID):
    id = Area.objects.filter(city_id=cityID)
    id = id.all().order_by('area_name')
    return render(
        request, 'files/index.html', 
        context_instance=RequestContext(request, { 'allarea': id }))
```

Comment: Can you show what error you're getting by tracing requests in the network tab of your browser?

Comment: when I choose any city then alert pop show and give 'error' text

Comment: Have you tried actually hitting that REST URL manually to see what it's returning and whether that's what your JS is expecting?

Comment: You are expected to return JSON/XML response for an AJAX request, it appears you rendering a template instead. Maybe that is causing the error.